# Pass variable into sql loader ctrl file

Tags: powershell, sql-loader

I have a number of csv files that I need to load into a database using batch and sql loader but now I would like to be able to change the csv file name within the ctrl file dynamically for each csv so that I do not need to write a ctril file for each csv.

I need basic help as to how to do this in a powershell script

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: We need more to go on than what is given. PowerShell code samples, CSV file names, and some CTL file sample data. You could probably use `Get-ChildItem -path "*.csv"` to get the CSV files. Then you could use `(Get-Content CTLFile) -replace "csvfilename\.csv","newcsvfilename.csv" | Set-Content`. Without examples of real code and data, everything is just a generalization.

Comment: Search for rename-item function, you will find tons of examples.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I used Poweshell. This was the code I resulted with  `foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Path .\csv -Name )
{
    if ($file -like '*Rank*')
    {
        sqlldr.exe userid/password@oracle control=ctrl_fb_file2.ctl data=$file log=log_file.log DIRECT=FALSE ROWS=1000 | Out-Null
    }

    if ($file -like '*Values*')
    {
        sqlldr.exe userid/password@oracle control=ctrl_file_1.ctl data=$file log=log_file.log DIRECT=FALSE ROWS=1000 | Out-Null
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Path .\csv -Name ) { if ($file -like '*Rank*') { sqlldr.exe userid/password@oracle control=ctrl_fb_file2.ctl data=$file log=log_file.log DIRECT=FALSE ROWS=1000 | Out-Null } if ($file -like '*Values*') { sqlldr.exe userid/password@oracle control=ctrl_file_1.ctl data=$file log=log_file.log DIRECT=FALSE ROWS=1000 | Out-Null } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Making use of `PowerShell` pipeline will make the code more readable and performannt:

```
gci -Path C:\path\to\fils\*.csv | foreach {
     switch -Wildcard ($file = $_.FullName) {
         '*rank*'   { sqlldr.exe ...data=$file...}
         '*values*  { sqlldr.exe ...data=$file...} 
     }
```